# Обмен сообщениями клиента с сервером Java

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток, нужно написать простой клиент и сервер используя сокеты в java, но столкнулся с проблемой что программа виснет если клиент тоже получает информацию. Мне необходимо что бы клиент обменивался сообщениями. Подскажите как это можно реализовать? Заранее спасибо.

```
client
public class Main {
    static ObjectOutputStream out;
    static ObjectInputStream in;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Socket socket=new Socket("localhost",4444);
    in=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    out=new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("Connected");
    write("Test");
    String str=read();
    System.out.println(str);
}

public static void write(String str) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    out.writeUTF(str);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    out.flush();
}

public static String read(){
    String str=null;
    try{
        while (true){
            str=in.readUTF();
        }
    }catch (IOException ex){}
    return str;
}
}


server
public class Main {
    static ObjectOutputStream out;
    static ObjectInputStream in;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(4444);
    Socket socket=serverSocket.accept();
    out=new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    in=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    System.out.println("Connected");
    String str=read();
    System.out.println(str);
    write("Test");
}

public static void write(String str) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    out.writeUTF(str);
    out.flush();
}

public static String read(){
    String str=null;
    try{
        while (true){
            str=in.readUTF();
        }
    }catch (IOException ex){}
    return str;
}
}
```

Comment: потому что клиент в бесконечный цикл ушел `while (true)`, поэтому и виснет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потому что клиент в бесконечный цикл ушел `while (true)`

тоже самое касается и сервера.

Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546123/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/546134#546134)  простого к-с приложения

Comment: но ведь там будет обмен строками в цикле, а мне еще нужно будет добавить логику в программу, как бы правильно написать пару методов для отправки-получения строки, что бы это не было зацыкленно. Например клиент отправил строку-сервер получил обработал-отправил ответ, а дальше уже пошли другие блоки кода в клиенте и сервере, а потом снова инициализировать подобный обмен?

Comment: внимательно посмотри реализацию получения строки в примере, там как раз ожидается завершения стрима

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо