# Диалог с Сервером со стороны Kлиента

Tags: java, javafx, сокет, клиент-сервер

Нужно чтобы *клиент* постоянно находился в режиме ожидания ввода команд со стороны пользователя. Эти команды затем отправляются на *сервер*.

Нашел много примеров *Клиент-Серверного* общения (Java).
Например этот: [Простейшее клиент-серверное приложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546123/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/546134#546134)

**В этом примере *клиент* ожидает ввода с консоли. А как сделать ожидание ввода с компонета управления, например *TextField* (JavaFX)?**

Есть идея, сохранять текст из *TextField* в некую переменную. *Клиент* будет раз в секунду проверять эту переменную на изменения. При изменении отправлять строку на *сервер*.

Либо обработать событие *ActionEvent* для *TextField* . Можно ли определить в *клиенте* функцию, которая будет получать строку и отправлять ее на *сервер*? Эта функция я полагаю должна вызываться из обработчика *ActionEvent* .

**Класс *клиент* выполняется в отдельном потоке относительно главного приложения, чтобы не повесить интерфейс пользователя. Есть ли способ поставить *клиент* в режим ожидания и включать его, только если нужно отправить сообщение на *сервер* ?**

Comment: отправлять что-то на сервер, после того, как нажата кнопка после ввода?

Comment: @michael_best Да, что написать в обработчике события ActionEvent? Можно ли определить в Клиенте функцию, которая будет получать строку и отправлять ее на Сервер. Эта функция я полагаю должна вызываться из обработчика ActionEvent

Comment: думаю есть смысл написать `onClickEvent`. А в нем уже `String s = whereStringIs.getText()`. А затем `s.sendSomeWhere();`

Comment: @michael_best Подвох в том, что при использовании потока System.in не нужно думать о том, что делать Клиенту во время ожидания. System.in является блокирующим и Клиент автоматически находится в режиме ожидания. Грубо говоря, как изменить поток ввода, что бы был с TextField а не с консоли?

Comment: как вы определяете, когда пользователь перестал вводить что-то в поле?

Comment: @michael_best По нажатию на клавишу Enter для TextField возникает событие ActionEvent, которое можно обработать

Comment: так в чем проблема?

Comment: @michael_best В том что классу Клиент нужно что то делать, во время того, когда не нужно ничего отправлять на Сервер. Иначе Клиент завершит свою работу и нельзя будет ничего отправить на Сервер

Comment: `while(someEvent?)`? но я все равно не могу понять, почему клиент вдруг завершит работу

Comment: это вопрос или утверждение?

Comment: @michael_best Если заставить поток Клиент в цикле while() все время проверять условие, такой поток будет бесполезно расходовать системные ресурсы

Comment: у вас есть решение получше?)

Comment: @michael_best Конечно нужен цикл while(). Но ожидание должно быть за счет функции wait(). Решение есть в ответе к этому вопросу

Comment: а у этого вопроса есть ответ?

Comment: @michael_best Добавил, теперь есть?

Comment: вопрос исчерпан?

Comment: @michael_best Да, но возможно есть лучшее решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно организовать приостановление и возобновления потока *клиент* с помощью функций *wait()*, *notify()* . Вот минимальная рабочая часть кода класса *клиент*:

```
public class MyClient extends Thread{

    private DataOutputStream ostream ;
    private DataInputStream istream;
    private Socket socket;

    private boolean isPause;
    private boolean isContinue;

    private String command;

    private final String HOST;
    private final int PORT;
    private final int BUFF_SIZE=64;
    private final GuiElement guiElement;

    public MyClient(String HOST, int PORT,GuiElement guiElement) {
        this.HOST=HOST;
        this.PORT=PORT;
        this.guiElement=guiElement;
        this.isPause=true;
        this.isContinue=true;
        this.setDaemon(true);

        try {
            socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
            ostream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            istream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            isPause=false;
            isContinue=false;
        }

        start();
    }

    public void run() {

        while(isContinue) {

            //-----waiting
            synchronized(this) {
                while(isPause) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        closeSocket();
                    }
                }
            }

            //-----sending command
            sendCommand();
        }

        closeSocket();
    }

    //-----invoked from the class that creates this Client thread
    //-----when the user has clicked the enter button on the input field 
    synchronized public void setCommand(String command) {
        this.command=command;
        isPause=false;
        notify();
    }

    private void sendCommand() {

        try {
            ostream.write(command.getBytes());
            ostream.flush();

            byte buf[] = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];
            int r;

            r = istream.read(buf);
            String data = new String(buf, 0, r);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            closeSocket();
        }
        Platform.runLater(() -> guiElement.print(data)); /* display a message on a GUI element  */
        isPause=true;
    }

    private void closeSocket() {
        try {
            if(socket.isClosed())return;
            else socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            isPause=false;
            isContinue=false;
        }
    }
}
```

После запуска поток *клиент* находится в режиме ожидания. При вызове извне (из основного потока, который обращается к потоку *клиент* например так: client.setCommand(some message) ) функции setCommand() устанавливается текущая команда и уведомляется о прекращении ожидания ( notify() ) . Далее поток выходит из блока while(isPause){...} для отправки команды серверу самостоятельно запуская функцию sendCommand(). После выполнения функции sendCommand() поток снова переходит в режим ожидания попадая в блок while(isPause){...}